# How to set public folders in O365 where only certain users can see them

Tags: exchange, office365

First off I'm new to O365, and indeed public folders, so hopefully this is a real easy one.

Atm I'm just trying to set up a public folder (for use with a shared calendar) which can only be seen by a few people. These are the steps I've taken:

1. From the O365 Exchange admin centre, I have created a Public folder mailobx
2. I have then created a Public Folder, and set folder permissions with only 1 user who has full access. This took a couple of hours to show up in Outlook (is that normal?)
3. I set the Public Folders Root Permissions for just the same user as above, again full access

When I looked at another user, they could also see the public folder.  I would have expected only users who I add to see them.  Any ideas how I can set it up this way please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... you can do it from within Outlook by going to the properties of the public folder and then in the Permissions tab, you can alter the Default User permissions.  I set it to None in this case and the folder disappeared for any none-named users.